# Passing std::map as a default argument parameter

Tags: c++, linux, dictionary, stl

I have a function like this :

```
int insert(std::string, std::string, std::map<std::string, std::string>&)
```

since the third argument is a reference, what is the correct way to give a default parameter to this argument?

What I want is to set `std::map<std::string, std::string>& = VAL` by default and use the map only if that VAL is not the default value.

Comment: I wonder why you need a default map to insert to? You can return a reference to a `static` local map from some function and use that as a default value.

Comment: if there is a map in the input, i insert it into the input map. else i insert it into another global map.

Comment: If VAL is an already existing map, that is fine.

Comment: In that case, create two versions of the function, with and without the map parameter. The one without the map parameter calls the other function, passing your global map as the parameter. Or use the above suggestion.

Comment: fair enough. the issue is i have a lot of functions that need this map as a default parameter. It will be a lot of work to create separate copy of each function with different arguments. I am thinking of inserting a fourth argument, an integer with default 0 if data needs to be inserted globally and 1 if data needs to be inserted locally. or something like that. i know its not clean, but if i dont find a decent solution, i wil have to go with that.

Comment: Why can't you make the global map the default parameter? `std::map<std::string, std::string>& = VAL`

Answer (score 5):

Rvalue won't bind to a non-const temporary.

But if default makes sense, you are probably not modifying it, in which case make it const and than `std::map<std::string, std::string>()` will work as default value just fine. I.e.:

```
int insert(std::string x, std::string y,
           const std::map<std::string, std::string> &m =
                   std::map<std::string, std::string>())
```

If you really need non-const reference, just create an overload with one argument that will pass local variable.

Ad comment: Ok. You *can* pass a global variable as a default argument. Simply

```
int insert(std::string x, std::string y,
           std::map<std::string, std::string> &m = GLOBAL_map);
```

I should warn you that a function that modifies it's arguments, especially non-first argument, is rather bad design and global variable even more so.

Comment: i need to add data to the input map.

Comment: i know that it will be a bad design and so wont be doing it. will try to find a better solution since i need to edit input data.

Comment: @PrasanthMadhavan: Just use the expression returning the default map in the argument. But I really think you should give more thought to the overall design (possibly ask a broader question here).

Comment: i think the best way to move is to overload the existing funtion. I will have a lot more work. but it will be mostly just copy/paste. so its good. :)

Comment: @PrasanthMadhavan: Well, perhaps you could instead encapsulate the logic in a class. If you described your overall situation in another question, I am sure you can get some good suggestions for the architecture.

Answer (score 0):

If you're passing a non-const reference, it is because you want
to modify it, and will pass it an lvalue.  From your text,
I gather that you want to modify the map, but only
conditionally.  In that case, the standard idiom is to pass
a pointer, with `nullptr` (or `NULL` or `0` for pre-C++11) as the
default argument, for which you do nothing.